# Why can't open the realtek audio manager?

Tags: windows-10, audio, realtek-hd-audio

I download and install the latest `0009-64bit_Win7_Win8_Win81_Win10_R282.exe` from its official website
[realtek audio manager](https://realtekcdn.akamaized.net/rtdrivers/pc/audio/0009-64bit_Win7_Win8_Win81_Win10_R282.exe?__token__=exp=1610515874%7Eacl=/rtdrivers/pc/audio/0009-64bit_Win7_Win8_Win81_Win10_R282.exe%7Ehmac=156e554f57b8baa5283c02caa51e33c66f1bfe7a2110594baff927c46b147031).

Why can't open Realtek Audio Manager in my Windows 10  to double click the  RtkNGUI64.exe ?

[image]

If i download the audio driver from asus official website

https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/misc/audio/Realtek_Audio_Win7-8-81-10_V6017770.zip

I can open the realtek audio manager ,but can't use the mic in the front panel.

So i download the audio driver from realtek official website,the result is that i can't open the realtek audio manager ,but can use the mic in the front panel.

Comment: did you tried to create a shortcut and open that with admin priviledge? I noticed some websites shows if you can't open RtkNGUI64.exe, you might need to update driver through device manger. Please check https://windowsreport.com/realtek-hd-audio-manager-wont-open/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried launching RAVcpl and RAVbg? Not sure which one of them is the real one, but others are neccessary for it to work properly. Try launching all of them, check registry because the success of installation, and restart. Maybe then..?